# How do I test crates with #![no_std]?

Tags: testing, rust

I'm writing a runtime for a programming language implementation in Rust. I'm planning on linking in this runtime with the compiled code I generate, so to keep the binary small I don't want to rely on `std`.

When I try to `cargo test` my runtime, I get errors saying saying that `std::slice::AsSlice` can't be found, which I found is because some of the test harness requires std library code.

How do I go about testing this code? Is there a way to conditionally include the `#![no_std]` pragma, i.e. still include the std library while testing? I've also tried creating a separate test crate with the std library included, `extern crate`ing the runtime crate into it and running my tests there, but that has introduced a whole new set of issues.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
#[cfg(test)]
#[macro_use]
extern crate std;
```

(The `#[macro_use]` part is optional.)

Comment: This seems like it should be the correct way to do this, but when I try it and run `cargo test` I still get the following errors: `error: attempt to implement a nonexistent trait std::cmp::PartialEq` and `error: failed to resolve. Maybe a missing extern crate std?`

Comment: Also I should mention that simply removing the `#[cfg(test)]` line makes everything work.

Comment: If you make it an unconditional `extern crate std;` then you've kind of lost the whole point of `#![no_std]`. You should instead provide your own module std in such cases, like this: `mod std { pub use core::cmp; }`

Comment: I figured out what my problem was. In addition to the `#[cfg(test)] extern crate std;` line, I also needed `#[cfg(test)] use std::prelude::*;` because prelude was no longer automatically being imported. One more quick question, if you don't mind: is there a way to still use directives like `#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]` with this setup?

Comment: @ZachSmith: `mod std { pub use core::fmt; pub use core::cmp; }` &c. &c. will make it work.

Comment: Rust 2018 Edition removes `extern crate`; is there an updated solution?

Comment: @Lucretiel: no it doesn’t: it simply makes it [unnecessary in most cases](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html#no-more-extern-crate). This solution should still be fine.

Comment: When doing this, I still get an error for lacking an allocator.

Comment: ^^ Looks like [rust-lang/rust#54010](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54010). Unsure why it only sometimes causes an actual error.

Comment: This does not work for me when I specify `#![no_std]` in the same file

Comment: > #[macro_use] part is optional in Rust 2015 and not required in Rust 2018.

Sorry what? It's optional in 2015 and not required in 2018? Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 28):

You can cfg_attr to conditionally set no_std.

```
#![cfg_attr(not(test), no_std)]
```

Comment: This is a better answer in 2022, especially given that extern crate is unnecessary.