# Could compiling my crate with a dependency on std in my integration test introduce some implicit usage of std in the library part of the executable?

Tags: rust

If my library is declared as `no_std`, can I use `std` for my integration tests, or could that implicitly change something in the library? I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185854/testing-crates-with-no-std), which implies that using std is ok in such a situation, but it doesn't explicitly answer my question.

Does the answer to my question change if I'm using `build-std` for a custom target instead of a prebuilt `std` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your library will not be affected by the crates that depend on it. That would be a horrible world.